# Named pipe to regular file

Tags: linux, named-pipes, fifo

Linux:
I have opened a named pipe - I can see

```
prw-rw-rw-  usrA usrA
```

But after I while, its changed to a regular file

```
-rw-rw-rw- usrB usrB
```

Any idea how this can happen? The ownership has changed too.
Funny thing is usrA is actually a more privileged user than usrB

Comment: Seems that a process is changing this. Needless to say that we need more information to answer

Comment: If you're working within some codebase, my best guess is your program is re-opening the named pipe as a regular file by mistake somewhere.

Comment: Understood..but I want to know how I would do it - how could I change FIFO to regular file...then I could trace back how it happened

Answer (score 1):

By renaming, as shown in this example:

```
mkfifo foo
ls -l foo
touch bar
mv bar foo
ls -l foo
```

Or this even simpler example:

```
mkfifo foo
ls -l foo
mv foo bar
touch foo
ls -l foo
```

Note that renaming is controlled by the permissions set on the *containing directory or directories* in Unix and Linux, not by the permissions set on the source or destination of the rename.